# Angularjs ui-jq daterangepicker value(s)

Tags: angularjs, daterangepicker

I have the following input:

```
    <input ui-jq="daterangepicker" ui-options="{
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    startDate: '2013-01-01',
    endDate: '2013-12-31'
  }" ng-model="dateRange" class="form-control w-md" />
```

With the following controller:

```
    app.controller('AnalyticDashboardController', ['$http', '$scope','$sessionStorage','$log','Session','api','activityService',  function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage,$log, Session, api,activityService) {

    $scope.dateRange = 'None';

}]);
```

However when changing the value the `dateRange` value is not changed.

[image]

So my question is how do i get the value of this dateRange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your HTML like this

```
  <input ui-jq="daterangepicker" ui-options="dateRangeOptions" ng-model="dateRange" class="form-control w-md" />
```

and the dateRange must have "startDate" and "endDate"

```
app.controller('AnalyticDashboardController', ['$http', '$scope','$sessionStorage','$log','Session','api','activityService',  function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage,$log, Session, api,activityService) {
    $scope.dateRangeOptions = {
            format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            min: "2015-05-01"
        };
    $scope.dateRange = {
                startDate: '2015-05-01',
                endDate: '2015-05-30'
            };

}]);
```